# Read number of lines containing a particular string

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have this [file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11734191/):

```
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart1,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.101,CRITICAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart2,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.102,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart3,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.107,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart4,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.108,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart5,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.109,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart6,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.110,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart7,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.111,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart8,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.112,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart9,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.113,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart10,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.114,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart11,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.115,CRITICAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart12,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.116,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart13,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.117,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart14,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.118,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart15,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.119,CRITICAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart16,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.120,CRITICAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart17,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.121,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart18,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.122,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart19,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.123,CRITICAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart20,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.124,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart21,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.125,INFORMATIONAL,
 ashcroft_hsv_340.mib,sCellEventTrap_02_00,.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600512,INFORMATIONAL,
 ashcroft_hsv_340.mib,sCellEventTrap_03_21,.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600801,MINOR,
```

I want to store the number of lines containing  adaptec.mib which is 21 here in this example.

How can this be done?
Using anything sed/grep/awk.

Comment: Is your file sorted exactly as your example?

Comment: yes. if you want to have a look at the whole file, then [file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11734191/).

Comment: Sam, your question , at least to me, sounds like you want to count lines from beginning till you see line saying "adaptec.mib" and stop counting. But in your file there's many lines saying adaptec.mib. So in reality, i think you want to count number of lines that don't contain adaptec.mib. Is that right ?

Comment: @Serg Have a look at this [comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/637926/read-number-of-lines-till-a-particular-variable?noredirect=1#comment911639_637927)

Comment: @SamFlynn I think "number of the lines" is not a very precise wording. I guess removing "the" and just saying "number of lines" more accurately states what you want to achieve. And I think "including" should be "containing". I didn't want to use the edit button because I don't feel sure that I understood exactly what you wanted.

Comment: I am receiving so much heat  for this question. Now I am afraid to ask another question. People might vent out their anger on that too.

Comment: @SamFlynn The question is a bit basic. But I would not consider it too basic for this site. Stating a question well is more important than how advanced it is. The question may have been asked before, but then it should be marked as a duplicate rather than downvoted. And until the last edit I could see it interpreted in two different ways. But that just means somebody should ask for clarification, or simply answer both interpretations of the question (`grep -n` and `grep -c` respectively). I don't think this question deserved that many downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` has a -c flag that allows to report number of times a string has been found.

```
$ grep -c "adaptec\.mib" inputfile.txt                                          
21
```

If you want to be slightly more strict in the matching, you can use: `grep -c "^adaptec\.mib," inputfile.txt`

`awk` can do that,too, though slightly more verbose.

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{count=0} /adaptec\.mib/ {count++;next} END {print count}' inputfile.txt
21
```

Comment: Hey Serg, what if I were to copy this and create a new file?  Example I search on the name of `ashcroft_hsv_340.mib` and then copy all the lines with this string into a new file.

Comment: If you want to be slightly more strict in the matching, you can use: `grep -c "^adaptec\.mib," inputfile.txt`

Comment: @kasperd may i add your exact comment to the answer ? Also, ^ should be \ escaped right ?

Comment: @Serg Sure, you can add it. And no, the `^` should not be escaped.

Answer (score 5):

If your [file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11734191/) is sorted just as above example above you can do `grep`:

```
grep "adaptec\.mib" filename | wc -l
```

output is 21.

**PS:** This will not be valid solution if file is not sorted

Comment: It works perfectly. May I ask what the ` \ ` does in `"adaptec\.mib"` ? because I was planning on taking the name `adaptec.mib` as an input into this command. Example `echo "Enter name of the file"     
read fname  grep "$fname" filename | wc -l `

Comment: The "\"  character escapes the "." so that it is included in the string.

Comment: if you not include the "\" then any name `adaptecXmib` will be i ncluded. For example `adaptecAmib` or .. .so use \ to escape the expansion of `.` and treated as`.` and not expansion character

Comment: It will work just fine, even if the file is not sorted.

Comment: @kasperd in this file is yes but in general no since this search for all existence of the string and count them so if the string is repeated at last for example then it count

Comment: @SamFlynn Why you remove the accepted sign?  This is the fifth time you did that with my answers on 5 different questions?!!! Why you are doing that?

Comment: @Maythux I guess because a later answer provided a solution that is slightly more efficient than yours.

Comment: @kasperd Im not just talking about this question! This is the fifth times. He did same action for 4 times before

Comment: @kasperd you are quite right. Now I realize why I got those down-votes all of a sudden. Its nothing against you man, seriously.  It says `click here if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution`. No doubt your solution was helpful Maythux, but Serg's solutions is just perfect and I am using that instead of yours, that's why I changed the accepted sign. Now if you want me to change that, I can accept your answer, even though i believe that Serg's answer is more efficient.

Comment: @SamFlynn No i dont want to switch the accepted answer, plus I didn't downvote you, plus I'm not talking about this question. you repeat same action for more than 5 answers. Anyway have a nice time !!

Comment: @Maythux Maybe it is just a coincidence. Maybe the reverse happened as well, I guess you wouldn't have noticed. The question about when it is appropriate to accept another answer instead of a previously accepted answer could be asked on meta.

Comment: kasperd is right, this has nothing to do with the file being sorted or with the number of occurences per line: it will Just Work ™

Answer (score 3):

For collating data from CSVs, I've had good results with a Python library called `csvkit` before. It's fairly fast and outputs to JSON (which was useful for me at the time).

```
sudo pip install csvkit
$ csvstat -c 1 -H --freq testfile 
{ "adaptec.mib": 21, "ashcroft_hsv_340.mib": 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `perl` way:

```
perl -ne '/^(?!.*adaptec\.mib)/||print' foo | wc -l
```

---

*Example*

```
$ cat foo
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart1,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.101,CRITICAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart2,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.102,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart3,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.107,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart4,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.108,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart5,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.109,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart6,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.110,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart7,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.111,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart8,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.112,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart9,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.113,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart10,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.114,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart11,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.115,CRITICAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart12,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.116,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart13,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.117,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart14,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.118,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart15,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.119,CRITICAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart16,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.120,CRITICAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart17,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.121,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart18,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.122,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart19,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.123,CRITICAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart20,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.124,INFORMATIONAL,
 adaptec.mib,sCSISmart21,.1.3.6.1.4.1.795.2.5.0.125,INFORMATIONAL,
 ashcroft_hsv_340.mib,sCellEventTrap_02_00,.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600512,INFORMATIONAL,
 ashcroft_hsv_340.mib,sCellEventTrap_03_21,.1.3.6.1.4.1.232.13600801,MINOR,

$ perl -ne '/^(?!.*adaptec\.mib)/||print' foo | wc -l
21
```